# IE8 CSS Relative position extra whitespace

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm facing a problem that I couldn't solve, When I add `Position:relative;` to a div it appears with sorta a white border, or extra space like in the image[image]

and if I remove  `Position:relative;` border moves to the parent which also has  `Position:relative;` and this is only on IE8.
Markup:

```
<div class="content clearfix">
    Some content goes here
         <div class="block">
               <div class="block_content" style="display: block;">
                 Some content goes here
              </div>
          </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
min-height: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
width:100%;
background-color:#ebebeb;
}
.block_content {
display:none;
position:relative;
margin: 25px 20px 15px 20px;
}
.block{
      overflow:hidden;
    width:58%;
    padding-bottom:60px;
float:right;
position:relative;
margin-right:10%;
background: rgb(222,222,222); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(222,222,222,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(222,222,222,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(222,222,222,1)), color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(222,222,222,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(222,222,222,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(222,222,222,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(222,222,222,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(222,222,222,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(222,222,222,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(222,222,222,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(222,222,222,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(222,222,222,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#dedede', endColorstr='#dedede',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

            box-shadow: 6px 6px 14px #333333;
        -moz-box-shadow:6px 6px 14px #333333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 14px #333333;
    }
```

demo link: http://bank.benseno.com.tr/Sunus.html
any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `clear:both` ? not sure if it helps but that might the problem

Comment: I think I did, will try again to make sure

Comment: yea, still same, didn't help :-(

Comment: `.content` has a negative z-index, for whatever reason. It's defined in the ie.css. When I deactivate that, I don't get a white border. I only can test IE10 in IE8 mode, though, not with the original IE8.

Comment: very strange problem, and also that didn't work on IE8 itself on XP or on IE tester on Win8 ..

Comment: @zeroflagL and anyway z-index thing was Just another fail few days ago to remove the border from the `.content`

Comment: isnt it somekind of illusion? becasue the outlines dont work?

Comment: illusion? I didn't get what you mean

Comment: Oh oops where my broser settings, was debuggin my own site haha.

Comment: Such weird... if (debugging) I uncheck/check again this: `body * {visibility:hidden;}` all the page dissapears and replaced with a black background, but the white "border" *still there*. What the hell. But behavior depends which DIV you selected... (?) Still searching, hope we can help you with this strange issue...

Comment: yes, this is the strangest nightmare I've ever seen :-( 
I need help with that damn site :S

Comment: So... do you want that white border?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, well, well, I think I have what that strage border comes from.

It's from that piece:

```
.maroon:before {
    border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

If you remove `content:"";` you don't see that border anymore.

Seems that IE8 it's making a mess with the parent. So, if you change parent `position:relative`or remove it, IE8 apply this style to the previous `relative` element. I don't know if this might be for the `filter` you applied to achieve rotation and that stuff...

Sorry for the incomplete info, at least we can target where's the issue... I continue studying, but now perhaps you or other user, knowing this, can help to fix it.

Comment: Dude, that worked like a charm :-)
thanks a lot for your afford, reputation is waiting for the complete Info "answer" of yours
:D

Comment: I'm glad to help! That css issues with "He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named" browser are autentic nightmares! ;)

Comment: yes, I don't usually Suppert IE lower than 9, I hate it, but I had to

Answer (score 1):

Since web browsers handle default CSS properties in very peculiar ways, it's always a good practice to reset your css before starting development. On my tests, I was able to solve the problem applying Eric Meyers's reset css technique, but it's important to note that it worked under an environment where the provided code was the only one present at the document.

Looking at the example website you provided, I can see that you already use an CSS reset solution, but you aren't using a css reset that was made thinking on HTML 5 pages (like that one). So, my advise is for you to use HTML5 Doctor CSS Reset instead. It's based on Eric Meyer's solution, and you can get it here: http://www.cssreset.com/

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with this line in `layout.css` (line 480):

```
.maroon:before{
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Remove the border and content, or change the class.

Comment: Excuse me... What's the difference with my answer?

Comment: @Arkana not much of one. we both found the answer around the same time. I wasn't aware you had already answered.